# getting Indian current datetime in java

Tags: jsp, datetime

I am writing a Jsp page to get current datetime and display. It works properly. But when I deploy the project on server which is in USA, I shows USA's current datetime. How to get Indian curr datetime   from server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It is just about the timezone.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Date date = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: I am doing the same but it is showing me time 6.59 instead of 12.36

Comment: did you debug and check because this is giving me 13:08 as of now

Comment: it's working locally but ,when i up my project on server ,showing Tue Aug 27 06:43:13 MSK 2013 now.